# iOS CoreData fetch in AppDelegate not reflecting CoreData values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, delegates

Just for ease I was only working with one entity with two attribute bool values (one is defaulted to 1 and the other is not set) and one managed object. These values changes match core data throughout my classes except in my app delegate.

A small walkthrough to what I'm doing. On first load if no managed object is found, one is created and a bool value of 1 is set to it.

```
    //in appdelegate
    NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SettingsData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

SettingsData *gameSettings = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]lastObject];
isLoaded = [gameSettings valueForKey:@"isLoaded"];
NSLog(@"isloaded: %i", isLoaded);

//checks for isLoaded bool which is defaulted to 1 in managed object
//creates nsmanagedpbject if value isn't there and sets default value for attribute bgMusic
if (!isLoaded) {

    NSLog(@"Create NsManObj and set default values");

    SettingsData *gameSettings = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SettingsData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [gameSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"bgMusic"];
    [_Bglayer play];
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


}
```

My main view(view 1) loads, it fetches the managed object and pulls the value for bgMusic and it comes back as 1.

```
//main view (view 1)
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = app.managedObjectContext;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error = nil;


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SettingsData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"SoundBoolInMain: %@",[ info valueForKey:@"bgMusic"]);
```

I move to the next view and change a toggle, data core is updated with the new bgMusic value now at 0.

```
//next view (view 2)
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = app.managedObjectContext;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error = nil;


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SettingsData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
SettingsData *newsettings = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]lastObject];
```

NSLog(@"SettingsBGBool: %@",[newsettings valueForKey:@"bgMusic"]);

```
//Toggle Code
if ([[newsettings valueForKey:@"bgMusic"]  isEqual: @NO]) {
        NSLog(@"Tap1");
        [newsettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"bgMusic"];
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Tap0");
        [newsettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"bgMusic"];
        if (![context save:&error]) {
           NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    }
NSLog(@"bgVal: %@",[newsettings valueForKey:@"bgMusic"]);
```

I move back to the main view(view 1) and it fetches the key and now pulls a value of 0. I close out the app completely(kill in multitask). I open the application and my app delegate fetches and pulls a value of 1, my main view( view 1) loads and it fetches and pulls a value of 0, I move to the next view (view 2) and that is also pulling a value of zero. If i repeat the process and change toggle the value back to 1 the change is reflected in view 1 and 2 and app delegate still shows a value of one. Now what the heck is going on?

I have even tried adding 4 boolean attributes and tried changing their values the same way and they change, but only for the classes. I watched them closely in app delegate and they start off as 0 in app delegate and upon kill and reload of the app their values change to 1 ONLY in the app delegate. Any other changes to those values are only reflected in the fetches done outside of the app delegate.

I'm also jail broken so I've navigated to my application folder and looked at the SQLite database and everything is as is should be with the value of any attribute being zero my app delegate still pulls a 1. People weren't joking when that said data core is a b***h!

This is my first post here and hope I've been descriptive enough, if not please let me know what you need to help me. Im grateful for any and all help you kind people can provide. I have been pulling my hair at this for two long nights and have had no progress. Please help me, you're my only hope. :]

**Interesting Side Note:** I can change values in app delegate and they will be reflected in the fetches done in view1 and view 2 but they will not in app delegate.

Comment: Could you show us the number of `NSManagedObject` returned by each request (in the app delegate, view1 and view2) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, your setup is completely ridiculous for this kind of data. Use `NSUserDefaults`.

Second, while your solution results in tons of code, getting the context from your app delegate makes it even more verbose. Better simply pass the context.

Third, you can be pretty sure that when you `save` and *afterwards* do a fetch the change will be reflected. If you get an unexpected result check these possibilities:

- You did not save.
- You changed the value again before trying to retrieve it.
- You retrieve the value before the save.
- You are showing another variable rather than the retrieved value.
- You are displaying the correct value in a wrong format.

Comment: Assuming you could resolve the issue, you should accept this answer.